# Most efficient way to find the nth highest number in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, mergesort

I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to find the nth highest number in an unsorted array. What I did was sort it with mergeSort then find the index of the nth highest number. I think this is more efficient than most searches but I am not quite sure.....

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ThirdHighest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int [] a = new int[]{3,5,6,7,8,2,1,10,9};
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
    mergeSort(a);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.print(nHighestValue(a, 3));

}
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length > 1) {
        int lengthLeft = arr.length / 2;

        int [] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, lengthLeft);
        int [] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, lengthLeft, arr.length);
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(arr, left, right);
    }
}
public static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right){
    int l1 = 0;
    int r2 = 0;
    while(l1 < left.length || r2 < right.length) {
        if(l1 == left.length) {
            result[l1+r2] = right[r2];
            r2 += 1;
        } else if(r2 == right.length){
            result[l1+r2] = left[l1];
            l1 += 1;
        } else if(left[l1] < right[r2]) {
            result[l1 + r2] = left[l1];
            l1 += 1;
        } else {
            result[l1+r2] = right[r2];
            r2 += 1;
        }
    }
}
public static int nHighestValue(int[] a, int n) {
    int index = a.length - n;
    return a[index];

}

}
```

Comment: Sorting is O(n log n). I think this can be done in O(k*n).

Comment: Damn my first question on stack and it sucks! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomized [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm works in average case complexity O(n). Practically it's very rare to be O(n^2). It uses quicksort's partition function

Answer (score 0):

Finding the *lowest* or *highest* from unodrered data can be done in O(n), as @alitereralmind demonstrates.

Finding the Nth highest (as requested) is more complicated, since you need to track the best candidates. That turns the scan into an N-deep insertion sort with values which aren't within the top N falling out the end. While that might be more efficient than doing a full sort, I'm not sure it's worth the additional coding effort on normal-sized problems... especially if a similar query might be issued again and the initial sort could be reused.